# R returns partial (incomplete) results from function

Tags: r, list, dataframe, types, metafor

I try to compare models in a meta-analysis that I calculated using the package *metafor* (rma.mv- or rma - function). I try to write a function that extracts specific values (here: just beta and the standard error) from *i* models and adds them to a data frame.

My problem is that the model results do not end up as data or as a data frame. The header repeats every row. When I turn the results into an object and try to call it, R just returns NULL.

*Edit. I missed the return. Now it is just returns one row!

Any advice is welcome.
Thanks,

```
#data1
effectsize1 <- c(0.25, 0.15, 0.36)
variance1 <- c(0.05, 0.026, 0.041)
#data2
effectsize2 <- c(0.52, 0.16, 0.27)
variance2 <- c(0.01, 0.09, 0.063)

#model
library(metafor)
model1 <- rma(effectsize1, variance1)
model2 <- rma(effectsize2, variance2)

# function
extract_results <- function(...) {
  x <- list(...)
       for (i in x){
       b <- as.numeric(i$beta)
       se <- as.numeric(i$se)
       df <- data.frame(b, se)
       }
    return(df)
    }

#results
          b        se
1 0.2359601 0.1098624
          b        se
1 0.4290981 0.1126032

res <- extract_results(model1, model2)
res
NULL
```

*edit

```
> res <- extract_results(model1, model2)
> res
          b        se
1 0.2359601 0.1098624
```

Comment: your function just `print`s and not `return` anything.

Comment: thank you. I edited it, but now it just returns one row?

Comment: It is because you are `return`ing withhin the for loop. i.e. you need to collect the output from the for loop combine and return

Comment: sorry, not quite getting what you mean or how to do it. I moved return outside the "for" loop, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Thank you very much again! All works perfect. Now, I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` should be outside the `for` loop i.e. combining the output from each of the iterations with `rbind` after initializing a 0 row dataset ('df')

```
extract_results <- function(...) {
  x <- list(...)
  df <- data.frame(b=numeric(), se = numeric())
       for (i in x){
       b <- as.numeric(i$beta)
       se <- as.numeric(i$se)
       df <- rbind(df, data.frame(b, se))
       
       }
       return(df)
    }
```

-testing

```
> res <- extract_results(model1, model2)
> res
          b        se
1 0.2359601 0.1098624
2 0.4290981 0.1126032
```